RabbitMQ Queue assigns job to different server
I am making a project using SpringBoot, RabbitMQ, Elastic Search and k8s. My project currently consists of 2 parts. While my 1st project performs the process of saving my logs to rabbitMQ, in my 2nd project I listen to the queues and save them to elasticSearch. I want to make my 2nd project not only specific to this project, but I want to make a general project to use it as a log project in all projects, I want to listen and record logs in all my existing projects in this project. For example, I want to create a carsqueue to listen to the logs in my cars project, and for my motorcycle project, which is a different project, I want to create a motorcyclequeue in the same logger project, and I want to manage all of these queues centrally in my 2nd project, but I want something like this, since the number of incoming requests to the server can be a lot, I want to manage the project centrally in my 2nd project (in my Logger Project) and I want to do this recording process so that each of my queues is on a different server, so I want to realize the load balancing event, how can I do this, what is the best method on this subject, how can I do it?
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {
    @Bean
    public Queue myQueue() {
        return new Queue( "logQueue" ,true);
    }
    @Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

@Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory  connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return template;
}}


 @RabbitListener(queues = "logQueue")
    public void receiveLogMessage(LogEntry logMessage) {
         logMessage.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        LogEntry elasticsearchModel = logMessageMapper.mapToElasticsearchModel(logMessage);
        logRepository.save(elasticsearchModel);
    }

In my current project, I can record successfully as in the code I shared, but I want to make this project my main logger recording project and while doing this, I want each queue to be handled by a different server.
